# Bootstrap push pull on two grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to make a responsive website. I have to column one is `<div class="col-md-4 column">` on the LEFT and other is `<div class="col-md-8 column">` on the RIGHT.

When I see it on sm or xs, every grid is changing to 12 column which is good.

I want the RIGHT column to appear first then the LEFT column.

This is what I have, which is not working.

```
<div class="col-md-4 column col-sm-push-12 col-xs-push-12">
<div class="col-md-8 column col-sm-pull-12 col-xs-pull-12">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://www.bootply.com/qlstG12Aea

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="r-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-push-4 col-md-8">right</div>
        <div id="main" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-8 col-md-4">main</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do it the other way. Declare for mobile first, `xs` and `sm` full width and on `md`-Devices push an pull it to the right order.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to change the order of your columns in your html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">column 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">column 1</div>
</div>
```

So, you really will be changing the order in LG and MD and SM and XS will show the real order of your html code.

Example working: http://jsfiddle.net/cj4vqxv5/